# Mac Ports vs Linux Synaptics Package manager

Tags: linux, mac, macports

Why doesn't Mac OSX have something like Synaptics built in to allow easy installation of third party applications? Ports seems to be a bit of a mess and doesn't always seem to work

Comment: What doesn't work?  I've rarely had problems with it (outside of dealing with a perl install).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like [Porticus](http://porticus.alittledrop.com/) might help?

[image: Porticus]

Feel free to post specific port-related questions as we seem to have a few MacPorts members here. Otherwise the [MacPorts mailing lists](http://www.macports.org/contact.php#Lists) are also very useful. One major difference between Synaptic and MacPorts is that MacPorts is only source-based, with no binary packages by default.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great. I'm assuming that you have been able to successfully install the MacPorts base system at least? Otherwise Porticus is not going to solve your "bit of a mess" as you stated in your question.

Comment: I installed MacPorts, but got a cryptic error message when trying to install erlang from the GUI. In the end I just did "port install erlang" from the command line and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ports isn't exactly part of of OS X, but already a 3rd party software you install.

As for front-ends, in addition to [Porticus](http://porticus.alittledrop.com/) you could also check out [Pallet](http://pallet.darwinports.com/), though the last time I tried it it seemed rather unstable.

Comment: Ack, please don't link to darwinports.com.